# Improving C++ algorithm for finding all points within a sphere of radius r

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, multidimensional-array

Language/Compiler: C++ (Visual Studio 2013)
Experience: ~2 months

I am working in a rectangular grid in 3D-space (size: xdim by ydim by zdim) where , "xgrid, ygrid, and zgrid" are 3D arrays of the x,y, and z-coordinates, respectively. Now, I am interested in finding all points that lie within a sphere of radius "r" centered about the point "(vi,vj,vk)". I want to store the index locations of these points in the vectors "xidx,yidx,zidx". For a single point this algorithm works and is fast enough but when I wish to iterate over many points within the 3D-space I run into very long run times.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve the implementation of this algorithm in C++? After running some profiling software I found online (very sleepy, Luke stackwalker) it seems that the "std::vector::size" and "std::vector::operator[]" member functions are bogging down my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Since I do not know a priori how many voxels are within the sphere, I set the length of vectors xidx,yidx,zidx to be larger than necessary and then erase all the excess elements at the end of the function.

```
void find_nv(int vi, int vj, int  vk, vector<double> &xidx, vector<double> &yidx, vector<double> &zidx, double*** &xgrid, double*** &ygrid, double*** &zgrid, int r, double xdim,double ydim,double zdim, double pdim)

{
double xcor, ycor, zcor,xval,yval,zval;
vector<double>xyz(3);
xyz[0] = xgrid[vi][vj][vk];
xyz[1] = ygrid[vi][vj][vk];
xyz[2] = zgrid[vi][vj][vk];
int counter = 0;

// Confine loop to be within boundaries of sphere
int istart = vi - r;
int iend = vi + r;
int jstart = vj - r;
int jend = vj + r;
int kstart = vk - r;
int kend = vk + r;

if (istart < 0) {
    istart = 0;
}
if (iend > xdim-1) {
    iend = xdim-1;
}
if (jstart < 0) {
    jstart = 0;
}
if (jend > ydim - 1) {
    jend = ydim-1;
}
if (kstart < 0) {
    kstart = 0;
}
if (kend > zdim - 1)
    kend = zdim - 1;

//-----------------------------------------------------------
 // Begin iterating through all points
//-----------------------------------------------------------
for (int k = 0; k < kend+1; ++k)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < jend+1; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iend+1; ++i)
        {
            if (i == vi && j == vj && k == vk)
                continue;
            else
            {
            xcor = pow((xgrid[i][j][k] - xyz[0]), 2);
            ycor = pow((ygrid[i][j][k] - xyz[1]), 2);
            zcor = pow((zgrid[i][j][k] - xyz[2]), 2);
            double rsqr = pow(r, 2);
            double sphere = xcor + ycor + zcor;
            if (sphere <= rsqr)
            {
                xidx[counter]=i;
                yidx[counter]=j;
                zidx[counter] = k;
                counter = counter + 1;
            }

            else
            {
            }
            //cout << "counter = " << counter - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

// erase all appending zeros that are not voxels within sphere
xidx.erase(xidx.begin() + (counter), xidx.end()); 
yidx.erase(yidx.begin() + (counter), yidx.end()); 
zidx.erase(zidx.begin() + (counter), zidx.end()); 

return 0;
```

Comment: `vector::size` does not appear in the posted code. Are you sure that's the slow part of the program? Also, you should never see `size` and `operator[]` in a stack trace in an optimized build because such simple functions always get inlined. Be sure to pass `-O3` to the compiler, or select a "release" build instead of "debug" from an IDE.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I greatly appreciate your timely response. I used a "release" build and this greatly improved the speed of my code.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, `size` is probably being used as part of the `[]` operator to detect bounds issues.

Comment: A relevant information to add would be your compiler, your compiler flags, and the OS. And also, how many calls you are doing to `find_nv`

Comment: Precompute `rsqr` before the loop instead of re-computing for each point.

Comment: @paxdiablo you are correct. I remember reading that in some forums

Comment: @quantdev compiler: Visual Studio Express 2013 / compiler configuration: release / # calls - at least 400 but at times it could be more

Comment: You're finding lattice points?  Or these arrays hold arbitrary points?

Comment: @user2885078 My point still stands: `size` will only be called by `operator[]` when you have enabled extra debug-oriented bounds checking. If you ask the compiler for a faster program, it will not check the bounds and will not call `size`.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I am finding lattice points on a 3-D rectangular grid not arbitrary points

Comment: @Potatoswatter - you are absolutely correct. Once I selected a release build the program ran much faster and no more size and operator[] lag...Sorry for being naive

Answer (score 1):

You already appear to have used my favourite trick for this sort of thing, getting rid of the relatively expensive square root functions and just working with the squared values of the radius and center-to-point distance.

One other possibility which *may* speed things up <sup>(a)</sup> is to replace all the:

```
xyzzy = pow (plugh, 2)
```

calls with the simpler:

```
xyzzy = plugh * plugh
```

You may find the removal of the function call could speed things up, however marginally.

Another possibility, if you can establish the maximum size of the target array, is to use an real array rather than a vector. I know they make the vector code as insanely optimal as possible but it still won't match a fixed-size array for performance (since it has to do everything the fixed size array does *plus* handle possible expansion).

Again, this may only offer very marginal improvement at the cost of more memory usage but trading space for time is a classic optimisation strategy.

Other than that, ensure you're using the compiler optimisations wisely. The default build in most cases has a low level of optimisation to make debugging easier. Ramp that up for production code.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As with all optimisations, you should *measure, not guess!* These suggestions are exactly that: suggestions. They may or may not improve the situation, so it's up to you to test them.

Comment: `pow` typically has an inline overload for integer power, mapping to an intrinsic, for just this reason. I'd guess that's why nothing showed up in his profiler trace. (So, who's measuring and who's guessing ;v) )

Comment: Mine was a suggestion, not a guess :-) If it doesn't help, don't use it, but at least you've discounted one possible area of attack. Updated to make that clear.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - unfortunately I am fairly new to C++ so dont entirely understand all the jargon. Are you saying that "pow" automatically will see that I am using an integer power and therefore optimize its implementation?

Comment: @paxdiable When you say to establish the maximum size of the target array - do you mean of xidx,yidx,and zidx?

Comment: @user2885078, yes, that was the idea. Rather than using a vector for these, create an array that you _know_ will be big enough (ie, whatever `counter` will reach) and use the array rather than vector.

Comment: @paxdiablo - great point. I will implement and measure the run times. Currently I am using "tstart = time(0); tend=time(0); cputime=difftime(tend,tstart)" to measure the CPU time. Is this the best way? It just produces results in seconds and I would like more sig figs.

Answer (score 1):

One of your biggest problems, and one that is probably preventing the compiler from making a lot of optimisations is that you are not using the regular nature of your grid.

If you are really using a regular grid then

```
xgrid[i][j][k] = x_0 + i * dxi + j * dxj + k * dxk
ygrid[i][j][k] = y_0 + i * dyi + j * dyj + k * dyk
zgrid[i][j][k] = z_0 + i * dzi + j * dzj + k * dzk
```

If your grid is axis aligned then

```
xgrid[i][j][k] = x_0 + i * dxi
ygrid[i][j][k] = y_0 + j * dyj
zgrid[i][j][k] = z_0 + k * dzk
```

Replacing these inside your core loop should result in significant speedups.

Comment: Note, you can hoist parts of these from the inner loops, but if the compiler is doing its job it will have hoisted them for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand these equations. What are x_0,y_0 and z_0 ? Also, in the second block of equations did you mean to wrote ygrid and zgrid on the 2nd and 3rd lines, respectively?

Comment: (x_0,y_0,z_0) is the coordinates of the first point in your regular grid. And you're right it should be `ygrid` and `zgrid` in the second block of code - fixing that.

Comment: I got this to work in my code and I got ~6% decrease in CPU time. This was iterating over 3600 points which resulted in the maximum number of points within the sphere to be ~200K.

Answer (score 1):

You could do two things. Reduce the number of points you are testing for inclusion and simplify the problem to multiple 2d tests.

If you take the sphere an look at it down the z axis you have all the points for y+r to y-r in the sphere, using each of these points you can slice the sphere into circles that contain all the points in the x/z plane limited to the circle radius at that specific y you are testing. Calculating the radius of the circle is a simple solve the length of the base of the right angle triangle problem.

Right now you ar testing all the points in a cube, but the upper ranges of the sphere excludes most points. The idea behind the above algorithm is that you can limit the points tested at each level of the sphere to the square containing the radius of the circle at that height.

Here is a simple hand draw graphic, showing the sphere from the side view.[image]

Here we are looking at the slice of the sphere that has the radius ab. Since you know the length ac and bc of the right angle triangle, you can calculate ab using Pythagoras theorem. Now you have a simple circle that you can test the points in, then move down, it reduce length ac and recalculate ab and repeat.

Now once you have that you can actually do a little more optimization. Firstly, you do not need to test every point against the circle, you only need to test one quarter of the points. If you test the points in the upper left quadrant of the circle (the slice of the sphere) then the points in the other three points are just mirror images of that same point offset either to the right, bottom or diagonally from the point determined to be in the first quadrant.

Then finally, you only need to do the circle slices of the top half of the sphere because the bottom half is just a mirror of the top half. In the end you only tested a quarter of the point for containment in the sphere. This should be a huge performance boost.

I hope that makes sense, I am not at a machine now that I can provide a sample.

Comment: this is very helpful and is a great idea. I am not entirely sure I understand had to implement this though. Lets say for example that I am slicing the sphere through the z-axis. So that I have many different circles, each at constant z values, containing all points in x/y plane. How would I determine the radius of each of these circles? Perhaps I could first slice in the x-plane at the center of the sphere to determine the radii first? Thoughts?

Comment: So to find the radius of the circle slice in the sphere, draw this on a piece of paper. Draw a circle on a piece of paper, this is the sphere viewed from the side, now from the center, call it c, draw a line up ward along the Y axis, let's call this point a, pick any point, this is the plane that you are going to slice the sphere. Draw a line horizontally through that cuts the circle at point a. Now you should see a T shape, from c to the point that your horizontal line cuts the sphere draw a line, this is the R from the center to the edge where the plane cuts the sphere. You now have a .....

Comment: ... Right angle triangle of which you know the length of two of the sides, the height at which you are slicing the sphere and the radius of the sphere. Using Pythagoras you can calculate the other length which is the radius of the circular slice.

Comment: I will update with a quick drawing and some further optimizations. Basically you only need to calculate the points for 1 quarter of the sphere all the other points are mirror images of the points in the first quarter.

Comment: I truly appreciate your unsolicited thorough response. I am going to take some time to look over this and implement it in my algorithm. Much appreciated, this may be very beneficial

Comment: No problem, I hope you are able to successfully apply this.

Answer (score 0):

simple thing here would be a 3D flood fill from center of the sphere rather than iterating over the enclosing square as you need to visited lesser points. Moreover you should implement the iterative version of the flood-fill to get more efficiency.

[Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)